# yii cGridView multicomment

Tags: yii

I'm not sure what is the way to do this , so here I ask:

I have a Person model and Event model, and a connection table Person_Event.

The interface that I got now works in the following way:

1. A person is logging in and his id is being send via URL
2. The person is selecting events he is interested in from the cGridView (checkbox column)
3. Writing some comment
   4.Pressing send button , and the following create action is being triggered:

   ```
   public function actionXcreate()
   {
       $model=new Person_Event;

       if(isset($_POST['Person_Event']))
       {                    
           foreach ($_POST['selectedIds'] as $eventId)
           {                               
               $pmodel=new Person_Event;
               $pmodel->person_id=$this->_person->id;  //the id of the person who is logged in         
               $pmodel->attributes=$_POST['Person_Event'];     //the comment                   
               $pmodel->event_id = $eventId;           //all the events he checked in the grid         
               if (!$pmodel->save()) print_r($pmodel->errors);                         
           }
           $this->redirect(array('site/success'));
       }
   ```

So far , all is logical and simple. However , what I end up is that the comment the person wrote is being duplicated to every person_event row in the DB.

I want to put a text box in each row of the grid , and the commnet that will be written there will go to the specific event.

Now , I found this topic in yii about "admin-panel"
which is kind of helpful , BUT:

I already have a foreach in the action , the one that matches the person's id with the event's id , so how can I put another individual comment for each combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default CGridView supports only basic functionality, you would need to extend CGridView or use an extension to make columns editable

Easiest way to do this is use something like `TbEditableColumn` from Yii-booster library 
see http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView#gridcolumns EditableColumn in the additional column types section

If you do not like or wish to use twitter-bootstrap styling a standalone extension like http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eeditable will help.

Alternatively you can extend CGridView yourself to extend it to support column level editing